# How to make a cost effective but scalable site?

Tags: python, lamp

Portal Technology Assessment in which we will be creating a placement portal for the campuses and industry to help place students. The portal will handle large volumes of data and people logging in, approximately 1000 users/day in a concurrent mode.

What technology should i use? PHP with CakePHP as a framework, Ruby on Rails, ASP.NET, Python, or should I opt for cloud computing? Which of those are the most cost beneficial?

Comment: Why all the CAPS? It looks like you're shouting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of those will do, it really depends on *what you know*. If you're comfortable with Python, use Django. If you like Ruby go with ROR. These modern frameworks are built to scale, assuming you're not going to be developing something on the scale of facebook then they should suffice.

I personally recommend `nginx` as your main server to host static content and possibly reverse-proxy to Django/mod_wsgi/Apache2.

Another important aspect is caching, make sure to use something like `memcached` and make sure the framework has some sort of plugin or it's easily attachable.

Comment: thanx for the answer, but what about the cloud computation?
any comments on this will be welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Language choice is important as you must choose language that you and your team feel the most comfortable with as you must develop mid-large size application. Of course use framework with Python it must be Django, with ASP.NET .NET or MVC.NET whatever you feel better with with Ruby ROR and with PHP there are too large amount of frameworks.

1000 concurrent users is not that much, especially it depends what users will do. Places where users will get large amount of data are better to Cache with with any caching engine you want. You need to design application this what so you can easily swap between real DB calls and calls to cache. For that use Data Objects like for Logins create an Object array of course if you need it. Save some information in cookies when user logins for example his last login, password in case he wants to change it, email and such so you will make less calls to DB in read mode ( select queries ).

use cookie less domain for static content like images, js and css files. setup on this domain the fastest system you can with simplest server you can, probably something based on Linux.

For servers, best advice is to either get large machine and set Virtual Boxes on it with vmware or other Linux based solution or to get few servers which is better because if on big server down you lost everything if one of 1 is down you still can do some stuff. Especially if you set railroad mode. Railroad mode is simple you set up Application server (IIS or Apache) on one server and make it master while you set up SQL on the same server and make it slave. On other server you set up SQL as master and Application server as slave. So server one serves IIS/Apache and Other one SQL, if one down you just need to change line in host.etc in order to set something somewhere else ( i don't know how to do that in Linux ).
last server for static content.

Cloud Computing, you will use if you want it or not. You will share resources with some applications as Google API for jquery and jqueryUI for instance but you create unique application and  i don't believe making core of application based on cloud computing will do any good. Use large site's CDNs for good.

Comment: lot of my queries were handled by your answer. thanx